# Normalize Scale does not work as expected

Tags: transforms

I have the following cylinder.  I want it to have .045m for x, y and z dimensions.  Currently, as shown in the pic, all 3 scales are not at 1

[image: Before Scale Normalizaton]

After I use ALT S to normalize the scale, the dimensions change to .0454 for x & y and .0451 for z.  Why do the dimensions change?  How do I keep them static at .045m?

[image: After Normalization]

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions and scale are connected, always one changed another.
Use on top menu Object -> Apply -> Scale. This set scale to 1, but keeps the real size (dimensions) the same.

Also can use Object -> Apply -> All transform. This set scale, rotation, and location to 1, 0, 0 respectively

Comment: Ctrl-A > Scale is easiest!

Comment: Applying the location is not always a good idea when you have moved the object away from the center... it will reset the origin back to (0, 0, 0) but the rest of the mesh will stay where it is. Can really mess up your geometry if you have e.g. a _Mirror_ modifier on it when it uses the origin... or when the origin was at a certain position which cannot be easily recovered with something like _Set Origin to Geometry_ for example... so almost always I would only recommend applying the scale since it causes most of the issues if not applied... and rotation only when it is needed.